# How to remove space from dropdown value while selecting in selenide Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenide

My source html-snippet:

```
<select id="X1" class=""> 
 <option data-auto="X-input-option" value=""> --Select-- </option> 
 <option data-auto="X-input-option-0" value="10 "> 10 -XYZ </option> 
 <option data-auto="X-input-option-1" value="100 "> 100 -ABC </option> 
 <option data-auto="X-input-option-2" value="200 "> 200 -MNP </option>
</select>
```

part of code

```
abc= ".//select[@id='X1']";

$(By.xpath(abc)).shouldBe(visible).selectOptionByValue(ID);
```

Issue is :Dropdown values has spaces in it , how to select a value by using selectOptionByValue if it has spaces.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please also share the html-source in your question.

Comment: Apologies I am posting for first time.

Comment: Attaching the HTML snippet

Comment: <select id="X1"  class="">                                                                                   
 <option data-auto="X-input-option"  value=""> --Select-- </option>
<option data-auto="X-input-option-0" value="10  "> 10 -XYZ </option>
<option data-auto="X-input-option-1" value="100  "> 100  -ABC </option>
<option data-auto="X-input-option-2" value="200  "> 200  -MNP </option>                                           ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I have a drop down which has certain values and values has spaces. Now I am trying to select value using XPath.     val -?> value (1 or 100 or 200)                                                                                                    $(By.xpath( ".//select[@id='X1']")).shouldBe(visible).selectOptionByValue(val);
Now My issue is how to remove spaces so that when I am passing value it matches the dropdown value. Thanks @Siebe Jongebloed

Comment: In your XPath you use: `abc= ".//select[@id='xyz']";`, but I don't see any `@id-` attributes in your html?

Comment: Hi @SiebeJongebloed - Its an example snippet                                                                                               abc= ".//select[@id='X1']";
val = 10
$(By.xpath(abc)).shouldBe(visible).selectOptionByValue(val);                                                My question is how to remove spaces or ignore spaces in values of dropdown to match the value I am sending (by using this - selectOptionByValue(val) ).Thanks

Comment: @Siebe Jongebloed . Can you please suggest a way ? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See i.e.:https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html

Than this could be your solution:

```
$(By.xpath(abc)).shouldBe(visible).selectOptionByValue('10 ');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?